# Infinite color animation sequentially in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation, android-jetpack-compose-animation

I've just learned how to animate a color from an initial value to a target value indefinitely. Now I want that animation to go through more colors.

This is what I've got so far:

```kotlin
@Preview(heightDp = 30, widthDp = 90)
@Composable
fun BlinkingPreview() {
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val ghosting = infiniteTransition.animateColor(Color.Green, Color.Black, animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(tween(8000))).value
    val overshooting = infiniteTransition.animateColor(Color.Black, Color.White, animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(tween(1000))).value
    val waning = infiniteTransition.animateColor(Color.White, Color.Green, animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(tween(1000))).value

    Row {
        Spacer(Modifier.fillMaxHeight().weight(1f).background(ghosting))
        Spacer(Modifier.fillMaxHeight().weight(1f).background(overshooting))
        Spacer(Modifier.fillMaxHeight().weight(1f).background(waning))
    }
}
```

This gives this output:

[image: 3 squares in a row, each animating its color independently]

What I really want is a single `Spacer` cycling between all those color ramps, like this (I've glued the previous output manually in GIMP):

[image: 1 square animating its color]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with `animateColor` from Green to Green and `keyframes` to set intermediate goals:

```kotlin
@Preview(heightDp = 30, widthDp = 90)
@Composable
fun BlinkingPreview() {
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val blinking = infiniteTransition.animateColor(
        Color.Green, Color.Green,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = keyframes {
                durationMillis = 10000
                Color.Black at 8000
                Color.White at 9000
            }
        )
    ).value

    Row {
        Spacer(Modifier.fillMaxHeight().weight(1f).background(blinking))
    }
}
```